# How can I log a user out of Wordpress before the page loads?

Tags: plugins, admin, hooks, actions, authentication

I would am using the code below so that on my wordpress site if `?logout` is appended to the end of the URL the user will be logged out. This works well - if the user visits a page such as `mysite.com/?logout` or `mysite.com/test-page/?logout` or any page where the `$_GET['logout']` variable is set s/he will be logged out.

```
if( isset($_GET['logout']) ){
    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'wp_logout',0);            
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that even if I add this action to `plugins_loaded`, which is at the very top of the [list of action hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), the page that displays will still show the user being logged in. If the page is refreshed on a subsequent load it will display the "logged out" version of the page, but not on the same request.

**Steps to recreate problem:**

1. Add this code to a plugin or perhaps to your `functions.php` file. I have it in a file in the `mu-plugins` directory.
2. Log into your Wordpress site.
3. Visit a page or post on your site, perhaps one with a comments box, and append `?logout` to the URL
4. The page will load as normal, the comments box will have your name and show that you are logged in and can leave a reply
5. Reload the page (with or without `?login" appended to the url)
6. The page is now logged out

**Desired Behavior**

After you are logged in to Wordpress visiting a page with `?login` appended to the URL will complete the logout process and display the page as if you were logged out when it loads - without having to refresh it.

I don't think I can hook into Wordpress any earlier, and so I'm not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', function(){
    wp_set_current_user(0);
},0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using either the `wp` or `init` hook instead.

Comment: this does not work. I tried those first. See the list of action hooks that i referenced in the question. `wp` and `init` both come after `plugins_loaded`.